# Testing a method which uses another method from the same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Recently I have gotten into unit testing my applications and have found myself at a bit of a difficult spot design wise in one of my classes.

I have a repository class which connects to the database, which looks a bit like this.

```
public interface Repository {
  ...
  void register(Account account)
  Account find(String email)
  ...
}
```

which, in implementation does this:

```
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {
  ...
  public void register(Account account) {
    if (find(account.getEmail() != null) return;
    // Account with same email already exists.
    ...
  }
}
```

This works fine in a live setting, but when unit testing it's a different story.

I use Mockito for mocking my dependencies, but I cant seem to mock the `find` method in the implementation class.

So my first thought was to inject a `Repository` in the `register` method which I than can fake, but that seems a bit weird since I provide a method with a class which it is a member of itself.

After that I thought to just copy the `find` logic to the `register` method, but that violates the DRY principle.

So.. any ideas on solving this design problem? I guess it's a common problem since it's quite standard to have unique emails in a system.

Thanks!

Comment: General remark: I would stay away from mocking internal methods, rather set up the  RepositoryImpl class so that find(account.getEmail()) returns the desired value. If this is not feasible, create an interface that is responsible for finding the account and pass an implementation of it to the constructor of RepositoryImpl (see [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)). This interface you may mock. After all, you want to the test the functionality of the class and not your mocking skills. Moreover, too much mocking causes fragile tests.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Made some changes with how the classes work, including injecting a new interface and it resulted in much smaller and easier tests (which I think is quite important in testing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to mock a method of the class under test you would need to spy it instead of using a concrete implementation:

```
// arrange
Account acc = new Account();
RepositoryImpl repoSpy = Mockito.spy(new RepositoryImpl());

doReturn(acc).when(repoSpy).find(Mockito.any(String.class));

//act
repoSpy.register(acc);

// assert ..
```

Thanks to that the register implementation will be used and the find method will be mocked to you liking.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about spies. Will give it a look!